# bash put command output to array

Tags: bash

I have a command

```
cat test.log | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -u
```

which returns: `8967 4376 0989 4321`

I want to put it in an array so I did

```
arr=$(cat test.log | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -u)
```

I can print it out with

```
for i in $arr; do  
    echo ${i}  
done
```

output: `8967 4376 0989 4321`

but when I try to access it by echoing each element

```
echo ${arr[0]}
```

returns `1234 1234 1902 4224 5883 8273`
and

```
echo ${arr[1]}
```

returns nothing

I have also tried putting each element in with(sudo code)

```
for i in command  
arr+=i
```

which did not work either. Can someone tell me what is the cause of this?

EDIT:
based on the post charles recommended, I tried going with map but it gives me a syntax error. Is this how im supposed to write it?

```
mapfile -t my_array < <( cat test.log | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -u )
```

Comment: thank you felix for the stylish edit. How did you do the code blocks? I led with 4 spaces but it still showed up as plain text.

Comment: You need to have vertical whitespace surrounding the four-space indents.

Comment: You need an emtpy line before the code block (and possibly after).

Comment: BTW, generally speaking, it's best to avoid using `cat` unless you absolutely can't avoid it. For some commands it's only a slight inefficiency (`cat test.log | cut -d: -f1` is only slightly slower than `cut -d: -f1 <test.log`), but for others the difference is huge (`cat test.log | tail` is **immensely** slower than `tail test.log` or `tail <test.log` when you're dealing with files of any significant size; same for `sort`, since it can parallelize with a seekable file handle but not a FIFO).